# Replicating rows for each unique group in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
Type  Sample  Version
C1    A       2
C1    A       4   
C1    A       6
C1    B       3
C1    B       5
C1    B       7
C1    C       1
C1    C       3
C1    C       5
C1    D       0
C1    D       0
C1    D       0
C1    D       0
C1    D       0
C1    D       0
C1    D       0
C1    D       0
.     .       .
C3    A       2
C3    A       4   
C3    A       6
C3    B       3
C3    B       5
C3    B       7
C3    C       1
C3    C       3
C3    C       5
C3    D       0
C3    D       0
C3    D       0
C3    D       0
C3    D       0
C3    D       0
C3    D       0
C3    D       0
```

and I would like to repeat the 8 rows of D for each Sample (A,B,C except D itself) and replacing in the replicated row Sample D with the corresponding Sample it has been replicated to.

It would basically add the rows of D to A, B and C. Rename D to A, B, and C. Remove D from the data frame.

The final data frame would look like this:

```
Type  Sample  Version
C1    A       2
C1    A       4   
C1    A       6
C1    A       0
C1    A       0
C1    A       0
C1    A       0
C1    A       0
C1    A       0
C1    A       0
C1    A       0
C1    B       3
C1    B       5
C1    B       7
C1    B       0
C1    B       0
C1    B       0
C1    B       0
C1    B       0
C1    B       0
C1    B       0
C1    B       0    
C1    C       1
C1    C       3
C1    C       5
C1    C       0
C1    C       0
C1    C       0
C1    C       0
C1    C       0
C1    C       0
C1    C       0
C1    C       0
```

I figured out how to achieve this by looping through Type and Sample:

```
for(i in unique(dataframe$Type)){
 for(j in unique(dataframe$Sample)){
   tmp <- dataframe[which(dataframe$Type == i & dataframe$Sample == "D"),]
   tmp$Sample <- j
   dataframe <- rbind(dataframe, tmp)
 }
}

dataframe <- dataframe[which(dataframe$Sample != "D"),]
```

There must be a better way of doing this using dplyr?

**Update: I have modified the final data frame to have it closer to a real case scenario, although it is still a simplified example.**

Comment: `expand.grid(Type = c("C1", "C2"), Sample = LETTERS[1:3], Version = c(1:3, 1:8)) %>% arrange(Type, Sample)`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out. Your suggestion basically recreates the desired data frame (before the update). I would rather have an approach that manipulates the initial data frame.

Answer (score 0):

With data.table, there's...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, {
  dd = .SD[Sample == "D", !"Sample"]
  .SD[Sample != "D", rbind(.SD, dd, fill=TRUE), by=Sample]
}, by=.(Type)]
```

which gives

```
    Type Sample Version
 1:   C1      A       2
 2:   C1      A       4
 3:   C1      A       6
 4:   C1      A       0
 5:   C1      A       0
 6:   C1      A       0
 7:   C1      A       0
 8:   C1      A       0
 9:   C1      A       0
10:   C1      A       0
11:   C1      A       0
12:   C1      B       3
13:   C1      B       5
14:   C1      B       7
15:   C1      B       0
16:   C1      B       0
17:   C1      B       0
18:   C1      B       0
19:   C1      B       0
20:   C1      B       0
21:   C1      B       0
22:   C1      B       0
23:   C1      C       1
24:   C1      C       3
25:   C1      C       5
26:   C1      C       0
27:   C1      C       0
28:   C1      C       0
29:   C1      C       0
30:   C1      C       0
31:   C1      C       0
32:   C1      C       0
33:   C1      C       0
    Type Sample Version
```